# ResourceWarning with opening os.devnull as a file and popen in Python

Tags: python, cross-platform, warnings, compatibility, popen

For comparability reasons I am using devnull as a file to redirect stdout (Python 2.7 does not have `subprocess.DEVNULL`)

```
subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=open('w', os.devnull))
```

However in Python 3.4 I am getting a resource warning when I use this

```
foo.py:107: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.TextIOWrapper name='/dev/null' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

Obviously there is going to be a resource leak. However does this matter for `/dev/null` or `nul`? Should I just suppress this warning?

I need to run this process for an unknown amount of time after the popen call while the program does other things so a context manager for the `devnull` resource will not work.

I thought of using `threading` to call `subprocess.popen` and close the file when the process ends, however I have to interact with the subprocess in the meantime, so `threading` will not work so easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that there is a standard-library module called `atexit` to register functions to be called on program termination. To use it with a file handler, you need to register the close method with it.

For example

```
import atexit
devnull = open(os.devnull, 'w')
atexit.register(devnull.close)
subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=devnull)
```

Now there will be no resource leak because the file is closed when the program terminates.